# Why are Texture2d arrays so expensive?

Tags: c#, textures, monogame

I'm building a 2d engine in C# and I have several static sprites that have multiple color variations.  Ok, easy enough, I create the Texture2D images at start time, then stuff them into an array, and use an array index at draw time.

This caused a surprising performance hit for me.

I made a quick simple test app where it draws the same 32x32 texture 1,000 times.  The baseline call takes  1.0001ms

```
spriteBatch.Draw(testTexture1, new Vector2(100, 100), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(16, 16), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

But this version, takes 11.0011ms!

```
spriteBatch.Draw(testTextureArray[i], new Vector2(80, 80), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(16, 16), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

Ten fold longer!
Same performance with a List.

Why is this and is there anything I could use instead of an array?

Comment: If this was C++ I'd say it's because you are copying the texture out of the array (which would be VERY costly) and passing it to the function, and maybe C# works that way too? Just a guess.

Comment: @BWG if they're value types, yes.

Comment: @OMGtechy I didn't know that C# even had value types :P

Comment: @BWG https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx :)

Comment: @OMGtechy So only structs and primitives can exist as value types?

Comment: Is it slow if you use several different variables, instead of using an array?

Comment: maybe it is because the spritebatch can't batch them ? maybe if you had a sprite-sheet .png converted into .xnb with those 1000 sprites would have been a different story ? how do you create those textures ?

Comment: Is the value of `i` constant for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Does testTextureArray[i] reference the same texture that testTexture1 references? Anyway if you don't mind releasing the project with the test case I'm sure one of us can figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: As evidenced by the discussion in the comments here, there are too many possibilities for why you are observing the noted timing differential. More information, particularly on the surrounding context and the method by which you are timing things, is needed to narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `testTextureArray[i]` is pointing to the same texture, you should have the same performance, but if not, then you are just hitting a design restriction of SpriteBatch.

Most implems of SpriteBatch I'm aware of (at least, XNA, SharpDX, Paradox, DirectXTk... though, don't know for sure about MonoGame...) are trying to batch draws with the same consecutive texture (see for example [here](https://github.com/SiliconStudio/paradox/blob/master/sources/engine/SiliconStudio.Paradox.Graphics/BatchBase.cs#L328), DirectXtk the C++ equivalent of SpriteBatch is assuming the same [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp) - look at method `void SpriteBatch::Impl::FlushBatch()`). If you switch between textures, the code path is much slower so this is not recommended to use SpriteBatch in this way.

As suggested by @Shiro, SpriteBatch is usually more efficient if you have packed all your sprites in a sprite sheet and use this same texture in your whole batch between Begin/End.

Comment: It's different textures on each draw.  Though, only from a set of ten textures.  I'm using it to produce variation in vegetation, as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/29NpvA8.png  According to the MSDN documentation, array values are stored and passed as reference types, so I thought it would be safe enough.  But then again calling array[0] for the texture gives pretty almost identical performance.  So i think it's like the example you gave above, I need to group the draws by texture, rather than location.

Comment: @EtanSivad It seems that you are confusing C# arrays and HLSL Texture2D arrays. The SpriteBatch implems are just accepting texture and not using behind the scene HLSL Texture2D arrays. When you call Draw with `testTextureArray[i]`, you are not passing an array but just a texture. It could be different if the implem was supporting it and you were calling with `Draw(testTextureArray, i, ...)` but this is not the case.

Comment: Oh, when I said calling `Draw(testTextureArray, i, ...)` it would require that testTextureArray is a GPU Texture created as a Texture2DArray (not an array of C#, that would be confusing - again! :D )

Comment: Sadly Texture2DArray doesn't seem to be implemented in Monogame.  That being said, your solution did work.  I re-factored the code so that it sorts the sprites in order by texture, then do the drawing.  It cut my draw time from ~60ms to 10ms.  Which is practically on par with drawing using a single texture.  Thanks for your help!